# How can I target variable in href in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, href

So the thing is I have 2 files. In one the url is redirecting to a variable of php and its orking fine the code is -

```
 function listdo_listing_website($post) {             
   global $post;                                                                
   $website = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_job_website', true);
   if(!empty($website)):                                                      
      echo '<div class="listing-review-btn"><a class="listing-website" href="'.esc_url( $website ).'"><i class="flaticon-unlink"></i><span class="text"> '.esc_html__('Book Now', 'listdo').'</span></a></div>';                                           
   endif;`
```

But I am trying to do this in another file but the code isnt working
the code -

```
<h3 class="listing-title">                   
                <a class="listing-website" href="'.esc_url( $website ).'"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
                <?php do_action( 'listdo-listings-logo-after', $post ); ?>
</h3>`
```

What is wrong with that?

I was trying to redirect a PHP variable in href but it isn't working

Answer (score -1):

You missed the echo on URL

```
<h3 class="listing-title">
  <a class="listing-website" href="<?php echo esc_url( $website ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   <?php do_action( 'listdo-listings-logo-after', $post ); ?>
</h3>
```

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: Do you get a value in your `$website` variable?